# Почему выводит только последнюю строку из файла?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Price4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String name = "D:\\product.txt";// в файле 3 строки
        if (args.length != 0) {
            FileInputStream inName = new FileInputStream(name); int i;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inName, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((i = br.read()) != -1) {
                char ch = (char) i;
                stringBuilder.append(ch);
            }
            System.out.println(stringBuilder); // а выводит одну последнюю строку
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Подождите, а зачем вам args? И ваш код прекрасно работает - выводит все строчки. Может, вы не тот файл считаете?

Comment: Тоже проверил у себя. Все хорошо работает. Потоки бы еще закрыть и все отлично. Думаю в файле поискать проблему

Comment: Читаю тот файл. В первый раз выводит верно. Потом выводит только последнюю строчку. Я 2 суток убил, ничего не понимаю, как так происходит. Файл проверял, строчки на месте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А если воспользоваться методом чтения построчно

```
import java.io.*;

public class Price4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String name = "D:\\product.txt";// в файле 3 строки
        if (args.length != 0) {
            FileInputStream inName = new FileInputStream(name); int i;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inName, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                System.out.println(line); // выводим содержимое файла на экран построчно
            }
        bufferedReader.close(); // закрываем поток
        }
    }
}
```